# Jquery Mobile Pop not opening on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, popup

I Have the next script:

```
function validateForm() {
    var mp = document.forms["local_storage_form"]["mphone"].value;
    var hp = document.forms["local_storage_form"]["hphone"].value;
    if (hp == "" && mp == "") {
        $('.tooltip2').fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('submit',1)
        $('.tooltip2').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#vaild').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).replaceWith('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">');
            $('#vaild').fadeIn("fast");
            $("#myPopup").load("ajax.txt");
            $('#myPopup').open;

        });
        setTimeout(function() {


            $.mobile.changePage("#rent");
        }, 5000);
    } 
}
```

and the function is activated by $(document).on("click") event,but the popup isn't opening,
i want the popup will stay for 5 seconds and then $.mobile.changePage will be activated.

What's wrong with my Code?

Comment: To open the jQM popup widget, use $("#myPopup").popup("open");

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include a $ sign in front of the page you're changing to. Following is the correct call:

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#rent'));
```

See the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ev0d4co5/2/) for a working demo.

Comment: My way worked too,but thanks.
The problem is with the Popup section.

Comment: the demo also includes the code for a standard popup.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi-colon on this:

```
localStorage.setItem('submit',1)
```

It should be:

```
localStorage.setItem('submit',1);
```

Comment: Thanks about the comment,but it is not the problem.:)